# why the output is 3 instead of 1,2,3

Tags: javascript

```
function rrr() {
    return (1,2,4);
}

n= rrr();
console.log(n);
```

when running this code I got the output 3,but I expected 1,2,3 as an output someone please explain this why the output is last element 3 instead of (1,2,3)?

Comment: Actually ,the output is 4 not 3

Comment: Perhaps you intended `return [1,2,3]`? The value of `(1,2,3)` is the value of the *last* operand in the expression, which is 3. See the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

`Comma` operator in JavaScript combines multiple expressions, evaluates the expressions from left to right, and returns the value of farther right expression.

Due to the same reason, `let x = (1,2,3);` assigns value `3` to variable `x`, `let y = (1,2,5-1)` assigns value `4` to variable `y`.